# How to pass a wordpress page title to a wufoo javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wufoo

I'm trying to enter the page title value in the javascript code from a wufoo form in a wordpress page.

I've added the following code:

```
'autoResize':true,
'height':'1092',
'async':true,
'host':'wufoo.com',
'header':'show',
'defaultValues':'field9=**boomboom**',
'ssl':true};
```

I need to replace the `boomboom` with the post page title so I can capture the name of the post every time the form is summited.

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate you help Dan,

```
<div id="wufoo-s121gtwf14azmyy">
Fill out my <a href="https://creativedoing.wufoo.com/forms/s121gtwf14azmyy">online form</a>.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var postData = {"postTitle":"<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"};
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">var s121gtwf14azmyy;(function(d, t) {
var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
'userName':'creativedoing',
'formHash':'s121gtwf14azmyy',
'autoResize':true,
'height':'1092',
'async':true,
'host':'wufoo.com',
'header':'show',
'defaultValues':'field1=**<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>**',
'ssl':true};

s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
try { s121gtwf14azmyy = new WufooForm();s121gtwf14azmyy.initialize(options);s121gtwf14azmyy.display(); } catch (e) {}};
var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');</script>
```

Comment: It's a bit off a mess. the code did not paste properly. Let me try again.

Comment: Done, should look exactly in my wordpress page.

Comment: I can see that worked for you ;) Just tried it again but got the same **< - I wonder if that is because it is a portfolio post and not a normal page.